# Why are HTML elements appending after the <script> tag

Tags: d3.js

I've been trying to append the `divs` on to the DOM below another `div` tag but they are all appending after the script tag.
HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="bg"> </div>
   <script src = "d3.v4.js">
   <script src = "scripts.js">
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var dataset = [ 10, 20, 30 ];
 d3.select("body").selectAll("div").data(dataset).enter().append("div").attr("class", "bg")
```

CSS:

```
div.bg{
 background-color:pink; 
 display: inline-block; 
 height: 100px; 
 width:10px;
}
```

It appears this way on DOM now :

```
 <body>
   <div class="bg"> </div>
   <script src = "scripts.js">
   <div class="bg"> </div>
   <div class="bg"> </div>
   <div class="bg"> </div>
   <div class="bg"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your elements are created after your DOM is created (when the script is executed)... so they by default they append at the last. Fix it by appending elements inside a container as below:

```
<body>
   <div class="container"> </div>
   <script src = "d3.v4.js">
   <script src = "scripts.js">
</body>
```

CODE

```
var dataset = [ 10, 20, 30 ];
d3.select(".container").selectAll("div").data(dataset).enter().append("div").attr("class", "bg")
```

CSS

```
div.bg{
 background-color:pink; 
 display: inline-block; 
 height: 100px; 
 width:10px;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="bg"> </div>
      <div class="bg"> </div>
      <div class="bg"> </div>
   </div>
   <script src = "scripts.js">

</body>
```